# Validation within a transaction with all violations in response

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to solve a problem with some sort of offline integration where data occasionally (once in several days) comes in a form of csv files. It can be new rows or updates for existing ones. Total amount can be around 1-2 million rows. And I need to guarantee the data consistency and referential integrity for every upload. And I need to provide a feedback about mistakes in incoming files.

I can do relatively memory efiecent check per row within the app that all required fields are provided and have expected types, but I want to do referential integrity in the DB.

So far I came up with following approach to do it within the transaction.

As example, the *schema* is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales_invoices(
    invoice_number TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    billing_name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales_invoice_lines(
    sales_invoice_line_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    sales_invoice_fk TEXT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT si_lines FOREIGN KEY (sales_invoice_fk) REFERENCES sales_invoices(invoice_number) DEFERRABLE
);
```

And the process is controlled from the app as follows:

```
START TRANSACTION; -- the app start transaction with
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

-- App does the batch insert for one table like
INSERT INTO sales_invoices (invoice_number, billing_name)
(SELECT r.invoice_number, r.billing_name
 FROM unnest($1::sales_invoices[]) as r)
ON CONFLICT (invoice_number)
DO UPDATE SET billing_name = EXCLUDED.billing_name;

-- And the batch insert for another table
INSERT INTO sales_invoice_lines (sales_invoice_line_id, sales_invoice_fk)
(SELECT r.sales_invoice_line_id, r.sales_invoice_fk
 FROM unnest($1::sales_invoice_lines[]) as r)
ON CONFLICT (sales_invoice_line_id)
DO UPDATE SET sales_invoice_fk = EXCLUDED.sales_invoice_fk;

-- And then select all violations like
SELECT * FROM sales_invoice_lines sil 
LEFT JOIN sales_invoices si ON (sil.sales_invoice_fk = si.invoice_number)
WHERE si.invoice_number is NULL;

-- If something is fetched then the app calls explicit rollback
-- and returns the data as the report further;
-- Commit otherwise
```

So my question is if there a way to do it in more optimal way as it's a trade off from faster transactions. And/or what are ways to optimise the current approach?

I'm in the middle of thinking to denormalise the schema and bring say a company/org unit id to use for table partitioning if it's going to grow to something big.
And the target DB is Postgres 9.6.